# How to initialize and set a 2D array in golang

Tags: arrays, go

I am trying to simplay make a 2D array as a field on an object. I want a function that creates the object and returns it. But when trying to create the 2d array it returns a single array.

```
type Struct struct {
    X int
    Y int
    Grid [][]bool
}

func NewLifeSimulator(sizeX, sizeY int) *Struct{
    s := &Struct{
        X:    sizeX,
        Y:    sizeY,
        Grid: make([][]bool, sizeX,sizeY),  //Creates a regular array instead of 2D
    }
    return s
}
```

What do I need to change so that my function initializes a 2D array?

Comment: You can also use maps. `s := make(map[string]map[string]bool)`

Answer (score 5):

The expression:

```
make([][]bool, sizeX)
```

will create a slice of `[]bool`s of size `sizeX`. Then you have to go through each element and initialize those to slices of `sizeY`. If you want a fully initialized array:

```
s := &Struct{
        X:    sizeX,
        Y:    sizeY,
        Grid: make([][]bool, sizeX),
    }

// At this point, s.Grid[i] has sizeX elements, all nil

for i:=range s.Grid {
   s.Grid[i]=make([]bool, sizeY)
}
```

The expression `make([][]bool, sizeX, sizeY)` creates a `[][]bool` slice with initial size `sizeX` and capacity `sizeY`.